# How do I pass parameters to Expression.New()?

Tags: c#, lambda

I was using this code, to create a compiled expression that constructs an object:

```
var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<IMyInterface>>(Expression.New(myType)).Compile();
exp();
```

But now I want to add a parameter to it, basically the constructor will type `SomeObject obj` as a parameter.

`Expression.New()` has an overload to take parameters. But I am not sure how to build them, or how to pass the object instance in.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you trying to pass a reference to an existing object? If not Expression.New(Type type) will call the parameter-less constructor of the specified type however it should be noted this will create a new object instance which may not be suitable here but in order to help I think I'll need a little bit more elaboration.

Comment: hmm, google returns the answer on SO fo *"Expression.New" C# passing parameters* (among others answer in first result  there is a solution which using Expressions)

Comment: Microsoft Docs refers to an overload passing the type as I mentioned above there.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.new?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_New_System_Type_

It should be noted that again this will only work when creating new object instances though. I'm still searching for anything that does what you're asking for. Nothing comes to mind off the top of my head though.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to create a `ParameterExpression` using `Expression.Parameter`. Then use other expressions like `ConstantExpression` or `BinaryExpression`.

[Here is a list of the different expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions?view=netframework-4.8)

This is just a quick example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var lambda = LambdaExpressionWithParameters();

        MyClass1 c1 = new MyClass1() { Name = "Hans" };
        MyClass2 c2 = new MyClass2() { Name = "Peter", Value = 42 };
        var b1 = lambda.DynamicInvoke(c1);
        var b2 = lambda.DynamicInvoke(c2);
    }

    static Delegate LambdaExpressionWithParameters()
    {
        ParameterExpression pex = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IMyInterface));//IMyInterface as Parameter 

        ConstantExpression cex = Expression.Constant("Peter");//Constant "Peter"
        MemberExpression mex = Expression.PropertyOrField(pex, "Name");//Property Name of IMyInterface
        BinaryExpression bex = Expression.Equal(mex, cex);

        return Expression.Lambda(bex, pex).Compile();
    }
}

class MyClass1 : IMyInterface
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class MyClass2 : IMyInterface
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IMyInterface
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```